# Ruby on rails rake task not returning up-to-date model info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scheduled-tasks, rake-task

While building a billing system I encountered the following problem:

In scheduler.rake :

```
@users.each do |user|
begin
  puts "CALCULATING COSTS =========="
  costs = user.total_billable_price_per_month(Time.now)
  lead_count = user.total_billable_leads_count(Time.now)
  click_count = user.total_billable_clicks_count(Time.now)

  puts "CREATING NEW INVOICES ======="
  @invoice = user.invoices.new

  # if user.free_credits
  #         invoice.total_price_in_cents = 0
  #       else
  #         invoice.total_price_in_cents = costs.cents
  #       end



  @invoice.total_leads = lead_count
  @invoice.total_clicks = click_count
  @invoice.total_price_in_cents = costs.cents

  # Als de vorige factuur onder de 10 euro was, dan geld bij huidige factuur optellen
  if user.invoices.last && user.invoices.last.total_price_in_cents < 1000
    puts "Bedrag onder 10 euro"
    puts "Last invoice = #{user.invoices.last.total_price_in_cents}"
    @invoice.total_price_in_cents += user.invoices.last.total_price_in_cents
  end

  puts "SAVING INVOICE FOR #{user.name} with ID = #{user.id}"
  # Factuur saven
  @invoice.save

  #Als de factuur hoger of gelijk is als 10euro, dan factuur aanmaken
  if @invoice.total_price_in_cents >= 1000
    #Moneybird factuur versturen
    puts "COSTS ARE HIGHER THAN 10 EURO, CREATING MONEYBIRD INVOICE"

    moneybird_invoice = MoneybirdInvoice.new
    sleep(15)
    moneybird_invoice.contact_id = MoneybirdContact.find_by_customer_id(user.id).id
    sleep(15)
    moneybird_invoice.details_attributes = [
         { :description => "Aantal leads", :amount => lead_count, :price => user.lead_price.cents.to_f/100},
         { :description => "Aantal clicks", :amount => click_count, :price => user.click_price.cents.to_f/100}
    ]

    puts "TRYING TO SAVE MONEYBIRD INVOICE"
    if moneybird_invoice.save && moneybird_invoice.put(:send_invoice)
      puts "SUCCESFULLY SAVED INVOICE"
      #GET UPDATED PAY URL
      @sent_mb_invoice =  MoneybirdInvoice.get(moneybird_invoice.id)
      sleep(15)
      @invoice.update_attributes(:moneybird_invoice_id => @sent_mb_invoice['invoice_id'], :moneybird_pay_url => @sent_mb_invoice['pay_url'])
    else
      puts "MONEYBIRD INVOICE FAILED"
      puts moneybird_invoice.errors.inspect
    end
  else
    # GEEN MONEYBIRD FACTUUR AANMAKEN
  end

rescue
  puts "ER IS IETS FOUT GEGAAN MET FACTUREREN USER ID = #{user.id} & NAME = #{user.name}"
  puts @invoice.errors.inspect
end
end
```

This piece of code should constantly increment each time the rake task is run, except when the total amount reaches > 1000.

```
if user.invoices.last && user.invoices.last.total_price_in_cents < 1000
  puts "Bedrag onder 10 euro"
  puts "Last invoice = #{user.invoices.last.total_price_in_cents}"
  @invoice.total_price_in_cents += user.invoices.last.total_price_in_cents
end
```

The code above always puts "Last invoice = 100" => This should increment each time the rake tasks is run

Every new invoice still has the same total_price_in_cents (when I'm expecting that it should increment).

What is going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Added after code upadte:

In your updated code, it looks like you were calling user.invoices.last after you called user.invoices.new, this is why it always returned the same value.

Create a variable @last_invoice = user.invoices.last before call user.invoices.new.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

In your original code posting, it looks like your `save` call on `@invoice` happened outside the loop -- I believe you're only saving it once.

```
task :create_invoices => :environment do  

  # Begin the loop for each use
  User.all.each do |user|
    @invoice = user.invoices.build
    #If last bill < 1000
    if user.invoices.last && user.invoices.last.total_price_in_cents < 1000

      puts "Last invoice = #{user.invoices.last.total_price_in_cents}"
      @invoice.total_price_in_cents += user.invoices.last.total_price_in_cents
      @invoice.save

    end # end 'if' statement
  end # end loop for all users
end # end task definition
```

So you loop though the users table, but never save updates -- except for the very last time after you exit the loop

Comment: I'm sorry Kevin, this was just a quick writeup, you are indeed right about the loop, but in my own code it's inside the loop, so this isn't the issue...

Comment: Can you post your actual code? Or update the above to reflect it more accurately?

Comment: I was overlooking the fact that I was calling user.invoices.last after I called user.invoices.new, this is why it always returned the same value. I now create a variable @last_invoice = user.invoices.last before I call user.invoices.new, this works fine. Thanks for your time Kevin!

Comment: Glad I could help! If you think my contribution helped you get to the answer, I'd appreciate an upvote and/or accepting my answer. Good luck!

Comment: Just answer with my solution and I'll accept it as an answer.